# The request matched multiple endpoints when migrated from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This two action routing works fine in `.netcore 2.1` but after migrate to `.netcore 6` shown error: `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints`
I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0 but could not resolved the issue.

```
//Just for two route /content/game & /content/software  
[Route("/content/{pageId=game}")]
[Route("/content/{pageId=software}")]
public IActionResult Index1(string pageId, [FromQuery] int page=1)
{}

//For all other url(/content/*)
[Route("/content/{package}")]
public IActionResult Index2(string package)
{}
```

Comment: The second one has two identically routes?

Comment: Ralf's comment above, and also your first action route starts with " /" while second doesn't, is it intended?

Comment: what do you actually expect to happen? I'd make your game/software routes explicit with their page names

Comment: it's typo. update question. error still shown.

Comment: I want to route `/content/game` and  `/content/software` to `Index1` and `/content/anythingElse` to `Index2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use regex to achieve it, Please refer:

```
//only match /context/game or /content/software

[Route("/content/{pageId:regex(^(game|software)$)}")]
[HttpGet]
public int Index1(string pageId, [FromQuery] int page = 1)
{
    return 2;
}

//For all other url(/content/*)      
[Route("/content/{package:regex(^(?!.*(game|software)).*$)}")]
[HttpGet]
public int Index2(string package)
{
   return 1;
}
```